# Visual Studio 2019 mkbundle not found, but I already installed mono and GTK

Tags: mkbundle

Visual Studio 2019 mkbundle not found, but I already installed mono and GTK
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctxm3.png)

mkbundle: The name "mkbundle" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correctness of the path, after which from p. experience. line: 1 character: 1 + mkbundle ConsoleApp1.dll --simple -o ConsoleApp1.exe + ~~~~~~~~       + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (mkbundle: String) [], CommandNotFoundException       + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Error messages are always better when they are as code snippet in the question (but in the case of Cyrillic language it might not be as helpful anway)

Comment: yeah, sorry, here it is: mkbundle: `mkbundle: The name "mkbundle" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correctness of the path, after which from p.
experience.
line: 1 character: 1
+ mkbundle ConsoleApp1.dll --simple -o ConsoleApp1.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (mkbundle: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException`